# Webaudio oscillator start() callback?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have an oscillator of a synth sound, I start it in a sequencer at different times. The below code gets run before my sound starts (this code can get run many times where time is a variable, before the audio starts).

```
osc.start(time);
osc.stop(time + 0.51);
```

So let's say this oscillator starts at time, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc. I have a callback for when it ends with the [onended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode/onended) callback of an oscillator node.

But how would I get a callback for when it starts?

Comment: Once you stop the oscillator, in order to start it again you need to recreate the oscillator and connect it to the destination. Only then you can start it again. Maybe you'll do this with a setInterval, but **you** control when it starts. So immediately after starting the oscillator you may call the "callback".

Answer (score 2):

After digging around a bit through documentation, it looks like what you're trying to do is no easy task for vanilla JS. However, I discovered recently a JS library called Tone.js. Using their library, oscillator nodes have a 'state' property that tells you when the oscillator is 'started' or 'stopped'. This might be helpful for you, since maybe it will allow you to write a function that triggers when an oscillator enters a 'started' state. Here is some relevant documentation for Tone.js: https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r12/OscillatorNode#getstateattime

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I was looking into Tone as well. I think they have Events specifically for starting and stopping, but need to look more into it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently and I approached the problem by creating a silent oscillator that stops at the same time as it starts. This enables you to control the timing of the `onended` callback.

The downside of this is that you have to cue your functions separately from the oscillator that you want to attach a callback to. However, it lets you achieve what you want using vanilla JS

```
cueFunction = (time, callbackFunction) => {
    audioContext = new window.AudioContext()

    const silentOscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
    silentOscillator.connect(audioContext.destination);
    silentOscillator.onended = () => {
      callbackFunction();
    };
    silentOscillator.start(time);
    silentOscillator.stop(time);
  };
```